Control when and how VScode shows docstrings of suggestions
When writing Python code in VScode, it recently started to also show the docstrings of the suggestions like in the following example

How does the right pop up with the docstring called? How can I disable it? How can I control whether to show it or not?

It turns out that VScode persists somewhere the state whether to show or not the documentation of a hint. By clicking the X on the upper right corner of the right box the documentation is closed and won't show up again in the future. If you later ask to "Show more" and see the documentation remember to close it.
